# Why launch intent in WallpaperService not working?

Tags: android, events, android-intent, touch-event, wallpaper

I looking for help with my Live Wallpaper. I wanna open Url and open calculator when i click on polygon. 
I have permission for that in Manifest: android:permission="android.permission.BIND_WALLPAPER" 
and this.setTouchEventsEnabled(true); in onCreate.
Why is it not working ?

There is my code:

```
 public void onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE){
            mTouchX = event.getX();
            mTouchY = event.getY();
        }else {
            mTouchX=-1;
            mTouchY=-1;
        }

        com.snatik.polygon.Point point  = new com.snatik.polygon.Point(mTouchX,mTouchY);
        if(polygon1.contains(point)){
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.wp.pl"));
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);

        }

        if(polygon2.contains(point)){
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_APP_CALCULATOR);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
```

Comment: Debug it and see it the polygon2 contains point

Comment: polygon2 contains point when i click it.

Comment: You debugged? Are you sure that the context you have is able to start a activity?